# PostgreSQL: How to return multiple row in subquery and find percentage for each individual row?

Tags: postgresql

**This query is supposed to find the percentage of error occured on particular  date but i am getting same percentage for all dates. Is there any way to return multiple rows from subquery.**

`select date(time) as day , ((select date(time) as day, from
 log where status != '200 OK')/(select date(time) as day from log )) as views from 
 log group by day;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
  date(time) as day,
  ((count(*) filter(where status!=200)) / 
  count(*)::decimal(5,2))::decimal(5,2)
from log
group by day
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select date(time) as day , count(1) / tot_err as views
From log, (Select count(1) as tot_err from log where status != '200 OK') 
Where status != '200 OK'
group by day;
```